# Get localized relative date Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Currently I use `Date(timeIntervalSince1970: dateDouble).relativeTime` to get relative time. And get string like "2 hours ago". Is there a way to get localized string?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
let timeInterval = 0
let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: timeInterval)
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
dateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true
print(dateFormatter.string(from: date)) // Today

// modifying locale

dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr_FR")
print(dateFormatter.string(from: date)) // aujourd’hui
```

check out https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1415848-doesrelativedateformatting

Comment: `doesRelativeDateFormatting` made my day!! 

Answer (score 1):

Well there is a library at GitHub called [NSDate-TimeAgo](https://github.com/kevinlawler/NSDate-TimeAgo) or the newer migrated version of it into [DateTools](https://github.com/MatthewYork/DateTools) Thanks to @Koen comment about it, it will make the job just easier to you, it supports a lot of languages and the way to implement it is very easy, you just need to have the Date for example:

```
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0];
NSString *ago = [date timeAgo];
```

It will format the date to be for example:

> A moment ago", "30 seconds ago", "5 minutes ago", "Yesterday", "Last
>   month", "2 years ago"

The trick is to reload the view to recalculate the time as needed from time to time using NSTimer/Timer.

Good luck.

Comment: Looks like TimeAgo is no longer maintained and has merged with DateTools: https://github.com/MatthewYork/DateTools

Comment: Your are right. http://github.com/MatthewYork/DateTools is modern and has swift pods.